# Creating a border or dropshadow that thins into the distance

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a curvy shape- it is supposed to represent a river flowing from the distance.
I want there to be a border to the shape, but I want that border to thin into the distance.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have to draw/paint it. None of the built in layer styles or filters will achieve perspective.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the drop shadow or stroke as Layer Effects to your existing shape, then convert the layer into a Smart Object, you should be able to use a Perspective transform.

An example.

This is a shape with a thick blue stroke, with added Layer Effects to add a black stroke and drop shadow

[image]

Converted to a Smart Object, with Perspective transform applied

[image]